# Reading "resource" files from different project on Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator, qt-designer

I'm building multiple projects using Qt where I want to store `resources` in only 1 of them (common project), where `resources` files get integrated into `.so` file. From other projects, I know how to refer to those `resources` files via `.so`, but don't know if/how it's possible on Qt Designer.

I imported the folder in the common prj that contains `.qrc` file and also the sub folders that contain resource files, by New File or Project --> Qt --> Qt Resource File (`.qrc` file and other files are disabled on the selection dialog). Still nothing shown from "Choose Resource" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but since I got here...

The Choose Resource dialog will be still be empty. You have to tell QT where to find the resources.

1. Click the Edit Resources
2. Click the button Add resource and select the *.qrc file
   The resources (icons, etc) should be displayed and ready to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The "Select Resource" dialog in the Designer showed nothing to me. Then I closed Qt Creator, delete the entire build folder, reopen Qt Creator, build the project, after that the "Select Resource" dialog in the Designer shows the resources.